# How to change 'users' auth table and use another instead Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8, breeze

So I just started a Laravel Project with Breeze, and I wanted to change the default table **users** , the problem is it didn't work, I did my research for days and I didn't get any successful result

I will try to explain what is the problem and what have I tried so far.

First, I created a new table called **users_data**, and this table, is completely different than the **users** table.
The fields that **users_data** has, are for example: *name_value*, *password_value*, *age_value*, *email_value*, etc. (I have to mention too that for the table **users_data**, it doesn't use a migration, because I already have an sql file, and added it directly to the db (I already have tables created, with primary keys, and foreign key, so i couldn't do the migration because it would take me a lot of time), and without the migration I can still get the data, so I don't think it could be this  the problem).

Actually I'am using Breeze, however, I used Auth scaffolding (PHP artisan make: Auth) too

*What have I tried:*

After several days of search, first I have created a new Model, called **UsersModel**, the content of this is the same as **User** Model however what I change is:

```
protected $table = 'users_data';

protected $fillable = [
    *name_value*,
    *password_value*,
];
```

and an extra function to override the default **password** of breeze or Auth (I guess):

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password_value;
}
```

next I went to **conf/auth.php**

there I specified the Model:

```
   'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\UsersModel::class,
        ],
```

and the table to use:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
| table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
| default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
|
*/

'table' => 'users_data',
```

after this I went to the view **login.blade.php**, and changed only the *email input* (for what I read on different pages, changing the *password input* will cause different problems, because I would need to make a lot of changes to make it work so the best idea is to override it with **getAuthPassword**, specified in the model):

new name input:

```
x-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="name_value" :value="old('name_value')" required autofocus />
```

After all this I went to **LoginRequest** (the validation for the login), where I replaced email for *name_value*

I tried to debug this:

```
dd(Auth::attempt($this->only('name_value', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember')));
```

and returns false

I noticed that there's a function in *vendor/laravel/ui/auth-back/AuthenticatesUsers*
called `username()`, that returns 'email'

when I saw that I remembered a page that said that this function could override too, so I changed the return value to name_value, and it doesn't do nothing

last, just to clarify,

I don't need the Register site I only need the login page, so for that in the $fillable I didn't add all the columns of the database, just the ones that I need to log in (*name_value*, *password_value*)

If anyone could help me and guide me it will be great, because I'am running out of ideas (I could do it with PHP alone, however, I need the *->middleware ['Auth]*, is there a way to activate the middlware if the user exists?)

Comment: I think it would also be helpful if we can see your LoginController class.

Comment: the problem is that i don't have a LoginController class, when i make it via Breeze it doesn't generate the LoginController(i don't know if it's version thing), however when i make it via  Auth scaffolding (PHP artisan make: Auth) it generates it. i'am more used to breeze however i could change to  Auth scaffolding alone

Comment: so how did you override the username method?

Comment: first i said that i override the username function that's located in vendor/laravel/ui/auth-back/AuthenticatesUsers, however i think i'am wrong about it I removed the changes made there and  override it in the new model i made 'UsersModel'

Comment: so i overrite the username function in the new model

Comment: Thanks a lot, for all the answers. I got the problem solved, in my case the passwords weren't encrypted in the DB(I know it's bad, but it's just old data, and now it's all updated), so when laravel tried to make the validation on the LoginRequest, using Auth::attempt, couldn't work, because the password needs to be encrypted, my old solution was to get the password (plain text), encrypted and use Auth::attempt to check if it's correct the validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's good practice to be editing vendor files. We don't push them to version control so other developers won't have your changes. Also, Laravel already has a way to override the username value without editing the vendor files.

Just use the trait in your auth controller like this:

```
public class MyLoginController {
   use AuthenticatesUsers; // or you can also use ThrottlesLogins trait

   // then override the username function here
   public function username() {
      return 'name_value';
   }
}
```

To override the password you can define this on your `User` model:

```
public function getPasswordAttribute() {
  return $this->attributes['password_value'];
}

public function getAuthPassword() {
  return $this->password_value;
}
```

I haven't tested this but based on the docs this is how you should do it. Also make sure to read this [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#introduction-database-considerations).

Comment: I didn't though, like that when editing the vendor files, good point, I will try to apply your answer and I hope it works, Thanks a lot!

Comment: jed I have a question, do I have to do the same with password?,                       public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password_value;
}, add this to the model or the controller like you showed me with username() and another thing, in the view login is it necesarly to let the password name as it is or can i changed(because the email name i changed for now)

Comment: @haruk1515 i've updated my answer. If you proceed to use `password_value` in your model, your input in your view should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

So you might have a model named users_data.php. Go inside it and change the code to something like that.

STEP:1

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\users_data as Authenticatable;  //Add this line for Auth.


class users_data extends Authenticatable   //Extends child from Authenticatable parent class obj.
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', .....];
}
```

STEP:2
Go to config/auth.php. You may found something like this below.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

Change the 'model' => App\Models\User::class, to 'model' => App\Models\users_data::class,
This is the main character in this drama that putting your application to users table by default.

STEP:3
Comment off the User.php so that no future conflict create.
Now your application has been diverted to your desired table and ready to login.